# Bluetooth not detected in Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Latitude E6230

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, dell

In the settings, it says that Bluetooth is not found and to connect a USB adapter to use it. I've double-checked the laptop specs and it definitely has Bluetooth.

I've already updated the kernel to 5.2.10, but it did not fix the issue. The next step seems to be to update the BIOS (my version is dated Nov 31, 2018; latest is Jan 2019), but it looks complicated to do as I've installed Ubuntu on a legacy boot (and not UEFI).

Are there any other fixes I should attempt before messing with my BIOS? Thanks!

EDIT: Added output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xocMD.png)

EDIT2: Ran dmesg | grep -i firm
Here is the output:

> [    0.113365] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
>
> [    0.151360] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
>
> [    3.382921] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I've appended a screenshot of the output at the end of the top level post.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy text from the terminal and post it as text.

Comment: I don't see any bluetooth adapter. It seems you don't have one or it is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0Ds_QdiR1Q). Your laptop doesn't have a bluetooth module.

Comment: In my case, some firmware files were missing. I figure it out because apt upgrade told me so. I had to add the missing *.bin files to the folder /lib/firmware/rtl_bt.

Comment: The specs for the E6230 say there should be one, but it was refurbished - maybe that was the catch. I can live without it, but that's still too bad. Maybe I'll do what that guy did in the video and try to install one myself if it's not too arcane. Thanks for people who pitched in to help!

Comment: Look for missing firmware files by running in a terminal: dmesg  |  grep -i firm

Comment: I ran it, I'm putting in the original post what I get in the terminal (something seems broken).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output image, Linux doesn't seem to recognize any Bluetooth card. Your wifi card ([intel 6205](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/59471/intel-centrino-advanced-n-6205-dual-band.html)) does not have Bluetooth integrated. Dell mentions that there is an optional bluetooth chip that might be included (Dell Wireless 380 Bluetooth). You might want to open up the case and check whether or not the chip is physically present, and if it is properly connected. If the card works under Windows then it is likely the problem is a missing driver, and the card might not be fully supported on the kernel.

Personally, I believe the better option would be to replace the wifi card you have for another one, that has Bluetooth integrated. It is an extremely simple process. Simply open the back cover, and on the top left you will see the wifi chip, Unplug both antenna wires, unscrew the card and place the new one, placing the antenna cables in the same position and screwing it.

You only have to be careful to buy a card that has the same kind of connection. The card you want is a half height mini pci-e. The newer cards usually have an m2 connector, which you do not want. I personally recommend the Intel 3160 (note that it is available in both pci-e and m2 connectors. You want the pci-e). You can find it on ebay for 10 usd, and on top of having integrated Bluetooth it is also compatible with  ac wifi, which offer better speeds and are usually less congested. Intel wifi chip cards also are fully supported on the kernel, so you won't have any compatibility issues or have to mess with drivers. If you search on Intel's site you can also find other alternatives that are also compatible with your laptop.

If you decide to replace it, those videos might be of interest:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfzOwlRc5RM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f1YmG3Jc0c

Comment: Thank you for your instructions, I will look into that if nothing else works. I have the option to enable or disable Bluetooth in the BIOS; would that be present if there was no Bluetooth hardware?

Comment: Yes, the option being present on BIOS makes no difference. It doesn't mean that there is or there isn't an actual Bluetooth chip installed.